# while using Pivot getting value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a query like this

```
select 
    * 
from 
   (select vtid 
    from Transaction_tbl 
    where dtime between '01-Apr-13 00:00:00' and '18-Jun-13 23:59:59' 
      and Status >= 5) p
PIVOT
    (count(vtid) FOR vtid in ([7],[8],[9],[11],[12])) as pp
```

Output for this query:

```
7           8           9           11          12
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
10          3           1           0           0
```

I have one more table `VType_tbl`.

Instead of hardcodeing `vtid` I want to load `vtid` from `vtype` table. How can I do that?

if any one know how to do it,,,please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the values to be unknown meaning you don't want to hard-code them, then you will have to use dynamic SQL to execute:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(vtid) 
                    from VType_tbl
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT  ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
                select vtid
                from Transaction_tbl t
                where dtime between ''01-Apr-13 00:00:00'' and ''18-Jun-13 23:59:59'' 
                  and Status >= 5
            ) d
            pivot 
            (
                count(vtid)
                for vtid in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Comment: out put is getting correct,,now column name is getting vtid(10,11,14,7,8,9),,,insted of vtid i want to show proper name i have table Vtype     like this                                              vtid        Vtype
----------- --------------------------------------------------
7           Normal
8           VIP
9           VVIP
10          Lost Ticket
11          Emaar Staff
14          IBS Staff

Comment: Insted of getting column name 10,11,14,7,8,9 i want to get proper name of vtid,,,how i can do that,,wherver you i given vtid mmi try to give Vtype,,,but getting some error

Comment: my self i resolved this issue,,,,now i got output what ever i expectd,,,thanking you once again